# Multiple styles for the same shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

I have a shapefile with the number of inhabitants per area and I should represent both the number of inhabitants and the density. I use to style both with categories.

How do you work in this case? Do you change each times the style of the layer or do you duplicate the layer to have the individual representations for easy check or something else?

Comment: Why not applying two visualization techniques in a rule-based symbology: 1. using a marker with its size corresponding to a number of inhabitants per area 2. and behind it graduated polygons for density.

Comment: Number of inhabitants is represented by different patterns, the density by different colors. If you're lazy, use data-driven colors.

Comment: @Erik where I can find info on your suggestion? Google do not helps me too much

Comment: @Taras where I can find info on your suggestion? Google do not helps me too much

Comment: @Ale look at a proper map representing both data. There's a reason why some symbologies/rules are used often - it's because they're effective, efficient and precise.

Comment: I can put it as an answer, but do not want to litter  =) i leave it here: https://imgur.com/a/snwrXCv